# Can you use ruby for web pages other than ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby

Is Ruby primarily only used in ruby on rails?  Is it used on the server side for general work like php is?  Also, I haven't seen a lot of hype about rails anymore.  Is Ruby and/or RoR dead or fading away?

I ask because I was interested in RhoMobile for building mobile apps, but I didn't want to get into using an antiquated language.

Thanks.

edit:  Can i use Ruby for web pages if I don't want to use rails?  (I do not mean another framework.  I mean like php.)

Comment: Ruby is used for plenty of things not web-related either. And no, it's certainly not fading away. Regardless of how popular it is/isn't, Ruby wouldn't suddenly become an "antiquated" language, either.

Comment: You can write a web page using shell or batch, they are that simple. Ruby is used for all sorts of heavy lifting tasks that are not web related. It's a great general purpose language that makes it easy to write robust code, unlike many other languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many web-frameworks for Ruby, not just Rails, [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) being one of them.

You shouldn't be deciding to use a language or technology, because there is or there is not a hype around it.

If a product is able to solve your problems, then you should use it. I know people building stuff in Smalltalk nowadays (who would have thought, right?), because it's great and it works.

Comment: Why would I want a dead product that is no longer being developed or adopted?  That's what I mean by hype.

Comment: If a product works for you - use it. I know people using Smalltalk nowadays, because it's great and it works.

Comment: Also, you certainly did get a wrong definition of [hype](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hype)

Comment: You can use [Rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/), this is a de-facto standard of how servers run Ruby code. If your code is Rack-compatible, it can be run by any Rack-compatible server.

There existed `mod_ruby` which was doing exactly what `mod_php` does, but it is no longer developed or maintained (or so I heard).

Comment: That answers my question.  It looks like the answer is not dead, but not used like php in web apps unless you use a framework.  I was looking for a usage like php where you just start using it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding your question about Ruby and/or RoR dead or fading away, look at the [job trends](http://www.indeed.com/jobtrends/Ruby-on-rails.html)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/), for example.
Also there is a lot of tools written entirely in ruby.